# Lerna. Is there a command to install devDependency only in root?

Tags: lerna, monorepo

According to [this comment](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1079#issuecomment-337660289),

> Indeed, devDependencies in the root package.json can be used in all
>   packages in the monorepo. This is generally used to co-locate
>   test-related deps and config (jest, eslint, etc).
>
> A couple caveats:
>
> This only works for non-CLI devDependencies. If you need to run a CLI
>   from a child package, that CLI needs to be in that package's
>   devDependencies. (transpiling, flowcopy, etc) All dependencies for a
>   given child package still need to be listed in that child's
>   package.json. (obvious, perhaps? just clarifying)

I see that `devDependency` in the root directory can be used for all packages. However, I can't see an obvious way to install `devDependency` only in root. Is there a such command or should I simply use `npm/yarn -D install` to do this? (or manually modify package.json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Yarn Workspaces, you can hoist shared dependencies in the root `node_modules`. To install dependencies in the root workspace, use the `-W` flag.

```
yarn add jest --dev -W
```

As you mentioned, these can now be used in any package.

[Source](https://leerob.io/blog/monorepo-lerna-yarn-workspaces)

Comment: Does this work with Lerna, or do you mean moving from Lerna to Yarn workspaces?

Comment: @watery Lerna and yarn workspacess can work perfectly well together: https://doppelmutzi.github.io/monorepo-lerna-yarn-workspaces/

Comment: @leerob how can you do the same with NPM?